# uri manipulation class .net

Tags: c#

Is there a decent OSS URI manipulation class for .NET?

Please dont suggest the BCL `Uri` class, or all other manner of manual hacks I could do around that almost useless thing.

I'm looking for a robust library to handle taking uris of all different forms (relative, absolute, with/without query string etc) that lets me access and manipulate all the fragments in an elegant way.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you tell us why `System.Uri` is almost useless to you we would be able to help more.  `System.Uri` is actually quite useful in my opinion so I don't really know what your needs are.

Answer (score 0):

Is System.Uri really that bad? I use it extensively, along with UriBuilder, and have never had any issues with it...

Comment: its utterly useless with relative uris? no querystring manipulation besides a single string? theres so much manual work necessary to make it usable

Comment: How is it "utterly useless with relative uris"? I manipulate relative URIs with it all the time.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for commenting 2.5 years after I posted the answer :-)

Answer (score -2):

When it comes to URL rewriting there are two ways you can go, you can either do it with a comprehensive IIS extension available at http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite .
However, if you're using a shared hosting account there's a way do it through asp.net called Routing. you can read more about it here. You can read more about it at 
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Manipulating a URL is not "URL Rewriting" in the sense you are using